# Google Tag Manager - Social Action Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

In Google Tag Manager, what do i put under "action target" in the social track type?

Network: twitter

Action: follow

Action Target:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target could be the content for which the "Action" was enacted upon.

(Friendly reminder to post only coding questions on SO.)